# Xcode crashes frequently when using self defined Enum

Tags: xcode, swift

It there any reason why Xcode crashes frequently when using self defined Enum. For example `BlurAction.ChangeMode(.Off)`, this line of code always make Xcode crashes.

Edit: I am using Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68).

I have the following code in two separate files.

TiltShiftMode.swift

```
enum TiltShiftMode {
    case Radial
    case Linear
    case Off
}
```

BlurControlAction.swift

```
enum BlurControlAction: Action {
    case Tap(CGPoint)
    case ChangeMode(TiltShiftMode)
}
```

Action.swift

```
// A marker protocol with no requirements.
public protocol Action {
}
```

Then in a `ViewController.swift` file type the following line

```
let action = BlurControlAction.ChangeMode(.Off)
```

Right after I type the dot before the Off, Xcode show an `encounter internal error` message.

Comment: Provide enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem (complete minimal verifiable example).

Comment: Please also post the stack trace of the crash and any error message that is printed to the console.

Comment: Have edit the question, hope you can reproduce the same issue.

Comment: What's an Action? Show its definition. And why are you giving the BlurControlAction enum a raw value type if you are defining an associated value for its one and only case? You are not allowed to have both; I'm surprised this even compiles.

Comment: For BlurControlAction I just show the minimal version of the definition, It have other case such as Tap, Pan in my real definition.

Comment: It's too minimal, then. I asked you to provide enough code to reproduce the problem. So far, the code you've given won't compile.

Comment: Okay, well now I can actually compile. But my Xcode does not crash when I enter your `let action` line.

Comment: I just tested the code in Playground, and the compiler seem to be happy. The crash seem only happen if the definitions are in separated files.

Comment: Then give me instructions on exactly how to distribute the code in files.

Comment: Do you get the same crash if you type `let action = BlurControlAction.ChangeMode(TiltShiftMode.Off)`? Just wondering whether typing the whole enum name helps things.

Comment: Yes typing the `TiltShiftMode` out does help. So I am thinking the compiler or Xcode is having troubling at inferring the enum type.

Comment: Right, I would refer to this as "the parser", the thing that tries to do syntax coloring as you type. Crashes of this kind used to be very common (daily, when Swift was first released). I would suggest that you file a bug with Apple if you can create a reproducible project, and meanwhile Don't Do That (i.e. type the full enum name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then in a view controller file, I add the following line `let action = BlurControlAction.ChangeMode(.Off)`. Right after I type the dot before the Off, Xcode show an *encounter internal error* message.

Well, you don't get the same crash if you type the line this way:

```
let action = BlurControlAction.ChangeMode(TiltShiftMode.Off)
```

So I would suggest typing it that way for now (and filing a bug with Apple).